# Using PHP for adding time values

Tags: php, time

From the database I get an array containing the following values (as time):

1. 00:00
2. 00:02
3. 00:01
4. 00:02
5. 00:02
6. 00:02

I would like to sum this values and return the number of seconds.

I wrote a PHP script like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $time += strtotime($values[$i]);
}

echo date('s', strtotime($time);
```

But I get 00 as output.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this values having hours and minutes (HH:MM) or minute and seconds combination (MM:SS) ?

Comment: `strtotime` returns a timestamp, it doesn't convert a string containing seconds to a number

Comment: HH:MM is the combination.

Comment: If you have *durations*, you shouldn't be storing them in a time format to begin with. Just store a simple integer with the duration in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to sum it separately .

Example. if you want answer in seconds and assuming HH:MM

```
    $seconds = 0;
   // loop through each time
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $value);
        $seconds += $hours * 60 * 60; //convert hours to seconds and add
        $seconds += $minutes * 60; //convert minutes to seconds and add
    }

    echo $seconds; //total time in seconds
```

Edit: I did not add any validation eg. "25:22" . That is your job.

Answer (score 0):

You have just the hour and minutes in your array, you need the seconds like 00:00:02.